# How to update the Vaadin UI from another view

Tags: java, asynchronous, vaadin7

In my vaadin application, I am having trouble updating the UI from another view.

This is the other view:

```
public class AbbyWindow extends Window{

private UI ui;

@Autowired
private Presenter presenter;

@Override
    public void attach() {
        super.attach();
        ui = getUI();
    }

private void saveData(){
    ui.setPollInterval(1000);
    mainUI.showSpinner();
    Presenter.saveData(param,param);
    UI.setCurrent(ui);
    close();
}

public void notifyUsers(){
    try{
        ui.access(() -> {
           mainUI.hideSpinner();
           Notification.show("Task completed"));
        });
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}   

}
```

And this is my presenter:

```
public class Presenter(){

@Async
public void saveData(args...){
    
    abbyWindow.notifyUsers();

}
```

It works If I am in the current view, but if I go to another view I am don't get the notification.

Do you know what the problem is? Thank you so much in advance.